# Freeing memory that was allocated in a function that returns a pointer to that memory (C++)

Tags: c++

I get a heap corruption error when I try to delete "z". I assume that z points to the allocated memory, so I'm confused as to why delete[] creates an error.

```
char* cpytoheap(const char* y)
{
    char* x = new char;
    for (int i=0; *(y+i); i++)
    {
        *(x+i) = *(y+i);
        *(x+i+1) = '\0';
    }
    return x;
}


int main()
{
    char* z = "asdf";
    z = cpytoheap(z);
    cout << z; //check that "asdf" copied correctly
    delete[] z; //error doesn't occur if this is taken out
    char y; //keep window open
    cin >> y; //...
    return 0;
}
```

I didn't use subscript in cpytoheap because the exercise is to copy to free store without using subscript. I would normally move on but I feel it may be important in the future to know how to free memory in this type of situation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Why are you allocating just one character?  Where are you calling `cpytoheap()` -- your `main()` calls `strdupa()`? Why don't you use `x[i] = y[i];` notation in the function?  You should set the null byte after the loop; you're wasting time doing it in the body of the loop.

Comment: You're not using cpytoheap() at all.

Comment: You don't appear to be calling `cpytoheap`. And since `z` was not allocated with `new[]` it is an error to free it with `delete[]`.

Comment: From MAN: The strdup() function returns a pointer to a new string which is a duplicate of the string s. Memory for the new string is obtained with malloc(3), and can be freed with free(3). So no delete [], eventually free.

Comment: @Jekyll: and the questioner's original code (since changed) wasn't even calling `strdup`, it was calling `strdupa` which is a glibc function that uses `malloca` for the allocation. This *can't* be freed with `free`, let alone `delete[]`.

Comment: C++ has `std::vector` and `std::string` to manage dynamic arrays reliably. There's no need to juggle pointers and hope for the best.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: there isn't even any need to juggle pointers and rigorously prove that your code is correct ;-)

Comment: I was sure I read strdup.. sorry people :)

Comment: You did read strdup... I'm sorry, it was a terrible error. strdup isn't used in this code, it was put in there by accident. It's edited correctly now, and my question was answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only allocated 1 char for `x`. Change it into

```
char *x = new char[strlen(y)+1];
```

to make sure enough memory space is allocated for the content.

Comment: `cpytoheap` isn't even called; this is *not* the cause. (It is an issue, though.)

Comment: Sorry, it's edited now. I changed the function name to cpytoheap for this post so it would make more sense, but I forgot to change it in main. Anyways this is a helpful answer even though the exercise said not to use subscript, I figured that it's unsafe to have an undefined size.

Comment: @nneonneo Given the OP's edits and comment, this *is* the problem.

Comment: @dvnrrs: Yep, I'm now seeing the edited output. Now that it calls `cpytoheap`, the allocation is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You used `strdupa` to allocate `z`, which allocates the result **dynamically on the stack**. Therefore, it should *not be freed*; it will automatically be deallocated when the current function returns. In that sense, `strdupa` is similar to declaring a local string variable in the current function.

You get a "heap corruption" error because your object isn't declared on the heap at all (`free` looks at the stack-allocated memory and doesn't see any allocation markers, so it assumes that the memory region is corrupted).

---

Also, in any case, you would not use `delete[]` to free an object allocated from a C function; if you need to free such a result, always use `free`.

Comment: If you use **`strdupa`** the memory is allocated on the stack and automatically deallocated. But, with **`strdup`**, the memory is allocated on the heap, so you have to `free` it yourself.

Comment: (Also, `strdupa` is not standard C, but a rather useful GNU extension.)

Comment: oh sorry I didn't notice he was using strdup**a**... :)

Comment: Okay, thank you. I had my function name as strdupa because the compiler gave me an error when I used the name strdup... I didn't even know strdupa was a function. Regardless all this information has been very useful!

Answer (score 0):

Your program have two error:

1. You are allocating not sufficient memory inside your function cpytoheap().
2. You have allocated the memory using new so you should use delete. If you have allocated using new[] then only use delete[].

To understand these problem you can use valgrind on GNU/Linux or WinDBG/PageHeap on Windows platfrom. The following report is generated by valgrind for your program.

```
mantosh@mantosh4u:~$ valgrind ./a.out
==4575== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4575== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4575== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4575== Command: ./a.out
==4575== 
==4575== Invalid write of size 1
==4575==    at 0x400A12: cpytoheap(char const*) (pratice.cpp:10)
==4575==    by 0x400A4E: main (pratice.cpp:19)
==4575==  Address 0x5a08041 is 0 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==4575==    at 0x4C2B1C7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4575==    by 0x4009D5: cpytoheap(char const*) (pratice.cpp:6)
==4575==    by 0x400A4E: main (pratice.cpp:19)
==4575== 
==4575== Invalid write of size 1
==4575==    at 0x400A00: cpytoheap(char const*) (pratice.cpp:9)
==4575==    by 0x400A4E: main (pratice.cpp:19)
==4575==  Address 0x5a08041 is 0 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==4575==    at 0x4C2B1C7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4575==    by 0x4009D5: cpytoheap(char const*) (pratice.cpp:6)
==4575==    by 0x400A4E: main (pratice.cpp:19)
==4575== 
==4575== Invalid read of size 1
==4575==    at 0x4C2BFB4: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4575==    by 0x4EC7288: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.18)
==4575==    by 0x400A63: main (pratice.cpp:20)
==4575==  Address 0x5a08041 is 0 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==4575==    at 0x4C2B1C7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4575==    by 0x4009D5: cpytoheap(char const*) (pratice.cpp:6)
==4575==    by 0x400A4E: main (pratice.cpp:19)
==4575== 
==4575== Invalid read of size 1
==4575==    at 0x53C8132: _IO_default_xsputn (genops.c:485)
==4575==    by 0x53C6069: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1393)
==4575==    by 0x53BBCDC: fwrite (iofwrite.c:45)
==4575==    by 0x4EC6FD4: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.18)
==4575==    by 0x4EC7296: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.18)
==4575==    by 0x400A63: main (pratice.cpp:20)
==4575==  Address 0x5a08041 is 0 bytes after a block of size 1 alloc'd
==4575==    at 0x4C2B1C7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4575==    by 0x4009D5: cpytoheap(char const*) (pratice.cpp:6)
==4575==    by 0x400A4E: main (pratice.cpp:19)
==4575== 
==4575== Mismatched free() / delete / delete []
==4575==    at 0x4C2A09C: operator delete[](void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4575==    by 0x400A76: main (pratice.cpp:21)
==4575==  Address 0x5a08040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 1 alloc'd
==4575==    at 0x4C2B1C7: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4575==    by 0x4009D5: cpytoheap(char const*) (pratice.cpp:6)
==4575==    by 0x400A4E: main (pratice.cpp:19)
==4575== 
asdf
q
```